# Plotting pieces on a checkerboard using pygame

Tags: python, pygame, logic

I am currently using pygame to make a **checkers game**. So far I have a function which successfully creates an **8x8** checker board (see below).

Now I need to make a function which places 12 pieces on either end of the checker board. I have a function which draws the pieces 'draw_piece' but can't get my head around how to go about plotting them on the checker board. If anyone could provide any suggestions/pseudo code that would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pygame as pg

class Board:
    
    GREEN = (34, 139, 34)
    CREAM = (245, 222, 179)
    ROW = 8
    COL = 8
    DIMENSIONS = 800
    SQUARE_SIZE = DIMENSIONS//COL
        
    #screen size is 800 x 800
    def draw_squares(self, win):
        win.fill(GREEN)
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(row % 2, COLS, 2):
                pg.draw.rect(screen, CREAM, (row*SQUARE_SIZE, col *SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))


     def draw_piece(self, screen):
        radius = SQUARE_SIZE // 2 - 15
        pg.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y), radius)
```

Comment: *"Now I need to make a function which places 12 pieces on either end of the checker board"* how do you want to arange the 12 pieces?

Comment: @Rabbid76 apologies for not clarifying, in the typical starting position for a checkers game. So on rows 0-2 every other tile (board colour[0]) and rows 5-7 on every other tile (board colour[0])

Comment: loop over every other square for n pieces from each end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a method that converts the row and column of a field to the center coordinate of the field and draws a piece with a specific color:

```py
class Board:
    # [...]

    def drawPiece(self, screen, colour, col, row):
        radius = SQUARE_SIZE // 2 - 15
        x = SQUARE_SIZE * col + SQUARE_SIZE // 2
        y = SQUARE_SIZE * row + SQUARE_SIZE // 2
        pg.draw.circle(screen, colour, (x, y), radius)
```

Use the method to draw a piece on a field. For example, if you want to add a piece to the top left of the field, the arguments for *row* and *column* are 0:

```py
board.drawPiece(screen, PIECE_COLOURS[0], 0, 0)
```

The *row* and *column* in the bottom right corner is 7:

```py
board.drawPiece(screen, PIECE_COLOURS[1], 7, 7)
```

Create list of tuples with the *rows* and *columns* of the pieces:

```py
pices_1 = []
for col in range(8):
    for row in range(3):
        if (col + row) % 2 == 1:
            pices_1.append((col, row)) 
pices_2 = []
for col in range(8):
    for row in range(5, 8):
        if (col + row) % 2 == 1:
            pices_2.append((col, row))
```

respectively

```py
pices_1 = [(col, row) for col in range(8) for row in range(3) if (col + row) % 2 == 1]
pices_2 = [(col, row) for col in range(8) for row in range(5, 8) if (col + row) % 2 == 1]
```

Draw the pieces in a loop:

```py
for col, row in pices_1:
    board.drawPiece(screen, PIECE_COLOURS[0], col, row)    
for col, row in pices_2:
    board.drawPiece(screen, PIECE_COLOURS[1], col, row)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that really helps!